# type Context is not a subtype of type BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart, typeerror, flutter-cubit

I have created a Flutter Cubit class that has a method that create an object of itself, the problem is when I try to create a variable of this class with this method I get a type error, so what is the solution?

```dart
class AppCubit extends Cubit<AppStates>{
  AppCubit ():super(AppIntialState());

  static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);
```

I tried to call this method with context, but I get the type error.

```dart
AppCubit cubit= AppCubit.get(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to provide the generic type, try changing this

```
static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);
```

to this

```
static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of<AppCubit>(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  static AppCubit get(BuildContext context) =>
      BlocProvider.of<AppCubit>(context);
```

You need to use `BuildContext` context inside get() or simply

```
  static AppCubit get(BuildContext _) => BlocProvider.of<AppCubit>(_);
```